Если создать дубликат списка через присвоение (s1 = s), то при изменении нового списка, будет меняться и старый?
собственно вопрос изложил выше. Заметил данную закономерность в следующем коде:
s1 = s
for i in range(len(s)):
    s1[i] = s[i][0]* ceil(s[i][1]/3)
    print(s,s1)

и в результате у меня выводит идентичные списки. Скажите это особенность питона? И что тогда делать, вместо присвоения через равно чтобы создать дубликат списка?

s1 = s[:] - так можно создать копию списка. Нет, это не особенность Питона. Во всех языках контейнеры не любят копироваться. Это долго и, как правило, не то чего хочет программист.

Насчёт«не то что хочет программист» я б поспорил  но долго и дорого, да.

Обычно в языках списки и другие сложные объекты передаются через указатели. Указатель при присваивании сохраняется тот же самый, список не копируется. Что касается питона, я лично люблю вызывать копирование в явном виде: s1 = s.copy(). Но это копирование только одного уровня, если уровней много, то нужно привлекать для копирования copy.deepcopy().

Ну и для чайников получается вариант s1.append()  в цикле перебора s

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Копирование списка делается неправильно

Используйте модуль copy для этих целей. Он встроен, и ничего скачивать не надо. Пример:
import copy
import math

s = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
s1 = copy.deepcopy(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
    s1[i] = s[i][0] * math.ceil(s[i][1]/3)
    print(s, s1)

Вывод:
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] [1, [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] [1, 6, [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]] [1, 6, 10]

Как видите, списки s и s1 отличаются.
Проблема заключается в том, что компьютер в целях экономии памяти делает ссылку на массив, а не новый массив. Модуль copy же не позволяет этого делать и заставляет компьютер создавать новый элемент, просто с такими же данными, а не ссылку на объект.
